# Timeout in Jquery to update the Dom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

Let's say I want to change the image source onClick and do some calculations. Whats happening right now is that the source changes when the the function exits. (Dom is busy?)

How can I make it so that the image source updates right away and then the function proceeds to the while loop?

HTML:

```
<img src="http://goo.gl/l55G2P" id="ImageSrc">
```

JS:

```
$( "#ImageSrc" ).click(function() {

    new_imgsrc="http://goo.gl/wBhyee";

    $("#ImageSrc").attr('src',new_imgsrc);
    test = 0
    do {
        test = test + 1;
        console.log(test);
    } while (test != 50000);
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/E3zvL/2/)'s a JSFiddle.

Comment: just wrap your loop in function and then wrap that with setTimeout(fn(){...}, 0);

Comment: @dandavis That approach did work. But is there no better way to get this done? And why set 0?

Comment: you set zero because you don't want to wait. i know of nothing "better".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I understand you correctly but you could use a timeout:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    //while loop here
}, 1000);
```

Where `1000` means 1 second. You could shrink this value so it doesn't wait as long.

As `click()` has no callback for `onComplete` I am not sure of a better way to achieve this.

Comment: `Click` has no callback for `onComplete` so no, not that I know of.

Comment: @dandavis I just think that there should be a better/straight-forward way to make Dom changes half way through a function. Not saying that the answer is wrong.

Comment: it would be nice, but the dom is slow and batching the updates helps speed things up considerably.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is actually a bit trickier than just setting a timeout, if you want to do it right.

The problem with setting is a timeout is that the timeout has to be large enough for the image to load. If the image isn't loaded within the timeout, it'll still have to wait for the loop.

What you have to do instead is actually give it a chance to update the DOM in between each step. To do this, you need to set up a timeout (or interval, but I prefer the timeout method since you have better control) that triggers every 0ms (basically, as fast as possible). However, since these are all timeouts, it has a chance to update the DOM in between two of these when it is ready.

```
console.clear();
$( "#ImageSrc" ).click(function() {
    loading_imgsrc="http://goo.gl/wBhyee";

    $("#ImageSrc").attr('src',loading_imgsrc);
    console.log("changed");
    doTest(0);
});

function doTest(test) {
    test = test + 1;
    console.log(test);

    if (test < 1000) {
        setTimeout((function() { return function() { doTest(test); }})(), 0);
    }
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E3zvL/4/

Comment: So basically, you replace one guess that the image might be loaded with two? The situation is bad in either case IMO.

Comment: I tried with 0ms and it doesn't. http://jsfiddle.net/E3zvL/5/ You have to be careful. If the image manages to load in less than 0ms (i.e., a couple nanoseconds) because it is cached or local or something, it will work. However, if it takes more than 0ms to do it, then it won't work, like it doesn't for me. The way I provided is more robust and guaranteed to work no matter how long it takes to load the image.

Comment: @webnoob I'm not sure what you mean by replacing one guess it might be loaded with two... all it is doing it allowing a gap for asynchronous operations (of any kind) to occur in between each loop. It's essentially making the loop itself asynchronous.

Comment: Sorry, I think I just misunderstood initially. Long day :)